# How do i solve problems while installing Magento 2?

Tags: magento

Hi,

This is my first attempt to manually install Magento on my server.

I am trying to run the process through cPanel.

I 've set the PHP version to PHP 7.3 (ea-php73).

I ve also increased the PHP parameters as below:

max_execution_time = 5000
  max_input_time = 5000
  max_input_vars = 5000
  memory_limit = 1024M

I downloaded the zip file (Full Release with Sample Data) from here https://magento.com/tech-resources/download and uploaded it in cPanel.

I then extracted the zip contents in the root location.

I create a database with a user and granted all permissions.

The problems i am facing are the below:

1. The unzipping/extracting never ends although i think that all files have been extracted.

2. When i browse the domain, the installation process starts successfully. At the last stage though (step 6), the status bar remains on 91%, at the point "Running data recurring...".

3. When i browse the domain, the login details i am entering are not working. I tried many times and also after clearing all cache.

Please advice.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I have a few notes.

1. Please avoid blindly increasing server parameters - you can end up in the black hole of issues later on. Take your time and check firstly if you really need to increase them.
2. Your memory limit is way to low. 1Gb is not even a bare minimum. Minimal required memory limit is 2GB (I recommend increasing it later one, depending on your project)
3. Always check system and technology stack requirements from the documentation firstly. https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html